# Include With statement in Teradata procedure

Tags: stored-procedures, teradata

I'm trying to create a procedure on a Teradata database which includes a `with/recursive` statement and when I `CALL` the procedure, it gives me the error `"Expected something like a name or Unicode delimited identifier between ( and )"`.  I deleted all the code that doesn't generate the error, and what was left is:

```
REPLACE PROCEDURE 
--CALL
db.test()
BEGIN
-- calling proc bombs instead of inserting, running outside called proc ok
INSERT INTO db.tbl_lProcModKey
WITH b AS (
    SELECT      TransactionControlNumber, ClaimLineNo, modifier
    FROM        db.tbl_lMod)        
SELECT TransactionControlNumber, ClaimLineNo, NULL AS modKey FROM b;
END
```

executing the code in SQL Assistant outside the procedure runs ok.  I'm assuming this is expected behavior for our database on VERSION 14.10.07.08, but is there another way to include this type of function in a scheduled process?  We'd like to use an SSIS package calling code on the database as much as possible, limiting the amount of code entered into the package.

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: I know that the WITH-clause was not supported within SPs in older releases, but I can't remeber when it was added. Appearently after 14.10 :( Of course you can rewrite it using Derived Table(s), unless it's a WITH RECURSIVE, but then you might consider storing the SELECT as a Recursive View.

Comment: or you can also just nest selects

Answer (score 0):

`WITH` is not supported in stored procedures, even in newer versions. Here is excerpt from 16.10 documentation ("SQL Data Manipulation Language"):

> You cannot specify a WITH or WITH RECURSIVE statement modifier in the definitions of any of these database objects:
>
> ∘ Views and recursive views
>
> ∘ Triggers
>
> **∘ Stored procedures**
>
> ∘ Derived tables

Comment: Seems to be a bug in the documentation :-)

Comment: @dnoeth Why? I've just tried to use query with `WITH` in a procedure and it didn't compile but without procedure it works (I didn't have much time to check if there is some other issue but I doubt). I work on Teradata 16.10.

Comment: You're right :-(  I never needed it in an SP or a Trigger, but at least 16.00 allows CTEs in both Views and Derived Tables